# Webservice which returns 2 parameters

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a webservice which returns me 2 parameters in VB.NET.

1. Redirect URL if the user is authenticated OR
2. Error occurred text

I am able to create a webservice which sends only one parameter that is either a URL or an error message.

Both are strings.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry its in C# - but should be straight forward to convert.

```
public struct MyResult
{
    public String RedirectUrl;
    public String ErrorMessage;
}

public class MyInterface : WebService
{
    public static MyResult MyWebServiceMethod()
    {
        MyResult Result = new MyResult();
        Result.Url = "http://Test";
        Result.ErrorMEssage = "Test";
        return Result;
    }
}
```